# EWS - Send Email With ConversationId (Not Reply)

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a conversation going on between the user I'm logged in as on EWS, and some other user. I know the conversation Id. I want to send the other person a message that is a part of the same conversation. I want to make sure that the message has the same conversation Id. But, this is ***not*** a reply. I want to send a ***new*** email that is a part of the same conversation. How do I do this in c#? The ConversationId property of EmailMessage is read only.

This article is of no help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn610351(v=exchg.150).aspx

Alternatively, I can actually get the latest email from the conversation from the server and reply using that with this code:

```
                var latestConversationNode = _ExchangeService.GetConversationItems(conversationId, new PropertySet { ItemSchema.Id, ItemSchema.ConversationId }, null, null, ConversationSortOrder.DateOrderDescending).ConversationNodes.FirstOrDefault();
                if (latestConversationNode != null)
                {
                    var latestEmailInConversation = latestConversationNode.Items.FirstOrDefault() as EmailMessage;

                    if (latestEmailInConversation != null)
                    {
                        var replyMessage = latestEmailInConversation.CreateReply(false);
                        replyMessage.Body = body;
                        replyMessage.Subject = subject;

                        foreach (var toRecipient in toRecipients)
                        {
                            replyMessage.ToRecipients.Add(toRecipient);
                        }

                        replyMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

This works sometimes, but for some reason, sometimes the reply doesn't appear as a reply in my inbox. I.e. my mail client doesn't recognize it as being a part of the same conversation.

I guess that what is happening is that the last email received on the server is not actually from the email address that I am sending to, and therefore either Exchange or my mail client don't realise that it's part of the same conversation even though the conversation Id is the same.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to accomplish with this? And what do you mean with "not a reply". Is it a forward, a new message or something else?

From my understanding, messages must not only have the same conversationId to be in the same conversation, but also have the same conversationTopic and a plausible conversationIndex (which is something like the conversationId concatenated with the timestamps of the mail-reply-history). 
If your mails get lost, you could take a look for inconsistencies in these two attributes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to send the other person a message that is a part of the same conversation. I want to make sure that the message has the same conversation Id

Comment: "From my understanding, messages must not only have the same conversationId to be in the same conversation, but also have the same conversationTopic and a plausible conversationIndex". I don't think that this is the case. You can change the subject of an email, and it will still be considered a part of the same thread by the mail client if it has the same conversation id.

Comment: Have you checked the conversationIndex?
Also check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490464/conversationid-property-vs-conversationindex-property-in-exchange-web-services-m

Comment: The conversationindex is that relative to the conversationid. It's just about where the particular message fits in to the conversation. I'm not sure how this helps, but a person that same thread is complaining about the same problem.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper Have you found a solution to your problem?