# Exchange calendar: Is ConversationId a good identifier of master events for FindItem occurrences?

Tags: soap, calendar, exchangewebservices

I collect the appointments in an Exchange calendar with a SOAP `FindItem` call. This returns single events and (custom) occurrences of recurring events.

When processing these I use `GetItem` to retrieve the ID of the master event for each occurrence (`ItemType`=`citOccurrence`). After that is done, I can determine if I still need to store the master event internally (and retrieve all its details), or if I have already done so.

But with many occurrence of the same recurring event (especially with unending ones) in a longer `FindItem` period, this means having to do a lot of `GetItem` 'get master' calls to the server (with the 1st one resulting in 'you must store the master' and all the others in 'you already have this master').

I have looked at the properties returned with `BaseShape` `AllProperties` and it seems that `ConversationId` could be a property that I can use to identify occurrences of the same master event. Sample data for test events:

```
<t:ItemId Id="AAMk[snip]AAEA==" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAABs2/j8u1jEQJde5BzoAC+PAAC5aMZ/"/>
<t:Subject>Occurrence</t:Subject>
<t:ConversationId Id="AAQkADgyMTc3ZTI4LTU1ZmItNGI5Yy04YzVjLTk2MjFiZjY5ODkyYgAQANxmlGQ/3ahArhg+mv+UJSo="/>

<t:ItemId Id="AAMk[snip]AAEA==" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAABs2/j8u1jEQJde5BzoAC+PAAC5aMZ/"/>
<t:Subject>Modified occurrence</t:Subject>
<t:ConversationId Id="AAQkADgyMTc3ZTI4LTU1ZmItNGI5Yy04YzVjLTk2MjFiZjY5ODkyYgAQANxmlGQ/3ahArhg+mv+UJSo="/>

<t:ItemId Id="AAMk[snip]RrAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAABs2/j8u1jEQJde5BzoAC+PAAC5aMaA"/>
<t:Subject>New single event</t:Subject>
<t:ConversationId Id="AAQkADgyMTc3ZTI4LTU1ZmItNGI5Yy04YzVjLTk2MjFiZjY5ODkyYgAQAMRNQtffkIdFvs73IVVJObM="/>

<t:ItemId Id="AAMk[snip]AAEA==" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAABs2/j8u1jEQJde5BzoAC+PAAC5aMZ/"/>
<t:Subject>Occurrence</t:Subject>
<t:ConversationId Id="AAQkADgyMTc3ZTI4LTU1ZmItNGI5Yy04YzVjLTk2MjFiZjY5ODkyYgAQANxmlGQ/3ahArhg+mv+UJSo="/>

<t:ItemId Id="AAMk[snip]RtAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAABs2/j8u1jEQJde5BzoAC+PAAC5aMaG"/>
<t:Subject>Meeting</t:Subject>
<t:ConversationId Id="AAQkADgyMTc3ZTI4LTU1ZmItNGI5Yy04YzVjLTk2MjFiZjY5ODkyYgAQAOZVB7gVSTJCtmZMMcXVBfQ="/>
```

Question: **Is `ConversationId` a reliable property to use for this?**

Notes:

- From reading around I get the impression that is primarily used for messages, not appointments.
- [There is a similar question here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/9ec9596e-1854-4a36-8f63-20148dfdefa3/difference-between-icaluid-and-conversationid?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) but that does not definitively answer mine.
- Also, [there are some issues retrieving ConversationId under Exchange 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490464/conversationid-property-vs-conversationindex-property-in-exchange-web-services-m), but [they seem solvable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487570/implementing-outlook-2010s-group-by-conversation-using-ews-and-exchange-2007).
- *(Edited to add)* [A quick test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PiZnjKJJuqUzRKYVhWLWFwUTA/view?usp=sharing) shows that `ConversationID`, `UID`, and even `InstanceIndex` are all candidates. Which is the 'definitive' one?

Answer (score 1):

Try iCalUID (I think that is the property, but I could be off a little).  If you have a multi-room meeting, the UID will be the same for appointments in both rooms.  I've not checked in some time, but I believe it will also be the same for instances of the same master.

Comment: See my edit to the question. Your answer does not sound yet as the 'definitive' one, so I'll wait a little ... UID has the advantage that's it's easier to retrieve under 2007. I'll do some more research.