# Exchange Web Services - how it recognize "global events"? There is no global ID

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using [php ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) to obtain events from Exchange, but it seems like there is no global id of event for all users. Microsoft write about it in docs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

User A is organizer and this event has one ID. User B is attendee, but ID for that event is different when I'm reading data from his calendar. Furthermore when some User moves this event to dumpster the event changes its ID in his calendar.

Is there a way to recognize event I'm looking for? I need to bind it to records in my PHP Application.

There is some `$UID` in `CalendarItemType.php` class of "pwp-ews", but `FindItem()`, and `GetItem()` don't get that property.

```
 /**
 * Identifies a calendar item.
 *
 * @since Exchange 2007
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $UID;
```

Comment: You are on the right track. It's UID you need to actually match them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31627879/512728 I cannot give much more concrete, because I stopped my code development for supporting meetings. There are some search mechanisms in FindItem that you can perhapse use?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I just add optional forth argument `$version` to `ExchangeWebServices()` and now `FindItem()`, and `GetItem()` returns UID.